# plotting contours in ggplot - geom_raster, geom_contour, geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, contourf, geom-raster

I have an interpolated dataset that I want to plot. When I plot it as geom_point, I see a lot of features that I am missing when I use geom_raster or geom_contour. Im guessing it got smoothed over? Is there a way I can plot this without losing the finer grain contours picked up in the geom_point? and the second figure looks terrible! is there a way to smooth this?

```
ggplot() + geom_raster(data = df, 
                             aes(x=X, y = Y, fill=Z)) + scale_y_reverse() +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlBu") +
theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()))


 ggplot(data=df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Z)) + scale_y_reverse() +
scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(ODV_colours)) +
theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()))
```

Comment: There's probably too _little_ data in your example. You only have 5 rows of data, with most of the dput being taken up by the `na.action` attribute, which isn't really helpful. Are you able to provide enough data to show graphically what the problem is?

Comment: I subsetted the data and tried to put most of it here. it did plot on my screen so I hope it's enough data, thanks Allan!

Comment: I've tried plotting what you have. There are only 6 points here. The geom point shows 6 points, the raster shows 6 tiles. It's not clear what the problem is from this example.

Comment: yes I see the problem! ive added it as a java script if that's better. ive just added the geom_point figure too.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any difference between the amount of detail in the points compared to the raster, other than the fact that they have different color scales which makes the detail harder to see in the raster. Perhaps try `scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(ODV_colours))` in the raster?

Comment: Well ive put both the figures I have up, the raster looks really bad, compared to the geom_point. is there a way to smooth this? - I dont know what the right word is.

Comment: You could do `interpolate = TRUE` in the raster? The problem is that the resolution of your data is quite low, so it's not clear what you expect.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be looking for a better 2D interpolation - I have provided an answer that shows how to do this. I have had to make a best guess at your palette though, as this was not included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a low resolution raster and you want to interpolate to make this less blocky. You could use `interp` for 2-D interpolation in this instance:

```r
library(interp)
library(ggplot2)

ODV_colours <- c('#fca878', '#d42b28', '#fbbf00', '#2cab1a', 
                 '#19b3e6', '#6f44fc', '#c767fa')


interp(x = df$X, y = df$Y, z = df$Z, nx = 1000, ny = 1000, linear = FALSE) |> 
  interp2xyz() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(ODV_colours), na.value = NA) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did a 2D interp using interp(x, y, z, xo=seq(min(x), max(x), length = 50), yo=seq(min(y), max(y), length = 50), linear = TRUE, extrap=FALSE, duplicate = "error", dupfun = NULL)
on the data here. I guess you're saying is that the interp I did was too coarse?
When I run your code on my dataset, I get 
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: @L55 if you think the raster looks too blocky, then yes, the interpolation is too coarse and you need to increase the number of points. Ultimately, you only have the data that you have, and interpolation is going to look odd if you try to do it on too few original data points. Something like a `gam` with x, y smoothing might give you a more natural appearance, but it does not truly interpolate points; it just gives a 2D surface which approximates your points smoothly. It really depends on the use case: accuracy versus 'nice' visual output.

Comment: @L55 I'm just using the exact `df` you shared in your question then running the exact code above.

Comment: thanks Allan! the df I shared in my question was already interpolated. so the code you provided does a second interpolation?

Comment: @L55 that's right. It would be best to simply do a higher resolution interpolation of your original data though, perhaps `interp(x, y, z, nx = 1000, ny = 1000)`

Comment: Hi Allan, in your code you had ```linear = FALSE``` does that mean it is not doing a linear interpolation? I have been trying to read up on this but if it isn't using linear interpolation, what is it using? and this reference here states that only linear and akima can be done using the interp function? https://rdrr.io/cran/interp/man/interp.html